# How can I find the inner limit of a line passing through a lune?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, curves

I have a crescent defined by two offset circles with different radii: a small one (let's call it `outer circle`) centered at (0,0) with radius `r` and a larger one (`inner circle`) centered at (0,-d) with radius `R`. The circles are positioned such that they create a lune (rather than a lens) and are separated on the y-axis by distance `d`. If I draw a ray out from (0,0) to some point on `outer circle` between its intersection points with `inner circle` (that is, on the outside edge of the lune), how can I find the point on that ray where it intersects with the perimeter of `inner circle`?

I need to sort this out because I'm trying to create a function in `Python` that will return random points within a crescent-shaped field by arbitrarily choosing an angle off of (0,0) toward a point in the outer arc, then picking a valid distance along that arc within the lune. I've worked out a way to select that angle, but I need to figure out what the minimum distance is along that random angle (which is, the point on `inner circle`'s perimeter the ray crosses it at). I know that the range on the radical line (`x = 0`) is `[(R-d)...r]`, and that there is only one valid point for the cusps where the circles cross, but that isn't super useful to me mathematically.

I've worked out a number of bits of information I need for it using [this resource](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html), but I can't quite get my head around this specific problem. I've taken a look around, but I'm not a mathematician and my nomenclature is probably a bit off...

Comment: As a footnote, it's actually not necessary that `inner circle` be larger than `outer circle`, as long as it intersects with `outer circle`'s perimeter on two points, but I feel like the constraint might simplify things? Maybe not...

Answer (score 0):

So you have a ray emanating from $(0,0)$ towards a point $(x,y)$. In your statement you assume that $x^2+y^2=r^2$, but that's not a requirement. Any point on that ray can be described as $(\lambda x,\lambda y)$ for some $\lambda>0$. The equation of the inner circle is $x^2+(y+d)^2=R^2$. Plug the point on the ray into that equation, and you get

\begin{align*}
(\lambda x)^2+(\lambda y+d)^2&=R^2 \\
(x^2+y^2)\lambda^2 + (2yd)\lambda + (d^2-R^2) &= 0
\end{align*}

which is a quadratic equation in $\lambda$. It has two possible solutions. In the situation you describe, one should be negative, the other positive. You'd want the positive one, since it lies on the ray.